# Suppose R is a partial order on A and S is a partial order on B. Define a relation T on A × B such that (a1, b1) T (a2, b2) iff a1 R a2 and b1 S b2.

Tags: solution-verification, relations, order-theory

Suppose $R$ is a partial order on $A$ and $S$ is a partial order on $B$. Define a relation $T$ on $A\times B$ such that $(a1, b1) T (a2, b2)$ iff $a_1 R a_2$ and $b_1 S b_2$. Is $T$ a partial order on $A \times B?$

So far:
$R$ is a partial order $A$ and $(a,a)\in R$.
$S$ is a partial order on $B$ and $(b,b)\in S$.
$T$ is a partial order and $((a,b),(a′,b′))\in T$.
In order for $T$ to be a partial order on $A\times B$ I know that it must be reflexive, transitive and anti-symmetric.
I'm a bit stuck on where to go from here though.

Comment: Why do you mention total orders in your attempt? Has the question anything to do with total orders?

Comment: You are 100% right, I'll take that part out.  For some reason i was imagining them as different when a partial order can be a total order so for this problem it wouldnt matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While formally speaking relations (and functions!) are sets of ordered pairs, it can be quite cumbersome to write everytime things like $(a,a)\in R$. The best thing to do most of the time is to manipulate $R,S$ the same way as $\leq, \geq, \ldots$.

- Anti-simmetry: $(a_1,b_1)T(a_2,b_2) \Rightarrow a_1Ra_2$ and $(a_2,b_2)T(a_1,b_1) \Rightarrow a_2Ra_1$ so $a_1 = a_2$. Same thing with $b_1, b_2$, so $(a_1,b_1)=(a_2,b_2)$.
- Transivity: $(a_1,b_1)T(a_2,b_2) \Rightarrow a_1Ra_2$ and $(a_2,b_2)T(a_3,b_3) \Rightarrow a_2Ra_3$, so $a_1Ra_3$. Same thing with $b_1,b_2,b_3$ so $(a_1,b_1)T(a_3,b_3)$.
- Reflexivity: $(a,b)T(a,b) \iff aRa$ and $bSb$, which is true.

Comment: Thanks for the response, simplifying everything like that is much easier to look at.  How would you go about finding the relation for T? That is the part that I'm really stuck at as the ordered pairs for A x B arent regular numbers

Comment: @Tunifish17 also the elements $a$, $b$ aren't necessary "regular numbers"... What do you mean by "finding the relation for $T$"? $T$ is a relation on $A \times B$

Comment: @Tunifish17 It seems, in your comment, like you acknowledge this answer as correct. The most proper way to do so is not thanking in a comment (although that's all right!); maybe you should consider to mark this answer as correct by clicking on the check-mark on the left and/or up-voting it, by clicking the up triangle close to it. That way, dcolazin will get some extra reputation (10 points for upvote, 15 for answer accepted) and you too (2 points for you for answer accepted, I think).

Comment: @dcolazin Isn't the question asking to define a relation T on A x B or is that another way of saying that we can assume the relation?

Comment: @Tunifish17 the question is "is the $T$ defined above a partial order"? $T$ is already defined when you say "such that (a1, b1) T (a2, b2) iff a1 R a2 and b1 S b2"